# Android - Detect image processing via camera?

Tags: java, android, artoolkit

Best wish for all. I have a problem about Image processing in Android.

I want to use camera to detect any things via camera and show it's name or show it's info. I intended that I will store dictionary image template or other ways.
I have research artoolkit in android for that. But I don't know I go truth way?
So that, I would like you to help me and give me any idea for my problem! :D

Thanks for your help and Best regards,
An Pham

Comment: The Website of ARToolkit sais: "ARToolKit for Android includes example source code for complete Android applications, with classes that can be reused in the developer's own applications, enabling rapid deployment of new projects." Have you had a look at these examples?

Answer (score 3):

Try using openCV. OpenCV is an opensource library for image processing and is also available for android. You need to know about what you want to detect and use the approach that will work for your type of detection.

http://opencv.org/

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is definitely a good library for what you are trying to do. It's used and actively maintained by large software companies. It's written in C++ but has Java wrappers.

The Android resources can be found here: http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

You can detect images using Haar-Cascades. There's a guide on how to create your own samples here: http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html
However, this requires many training pictures for each object you would like to recognize.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe is NOT an easy one. Definitely not a kind of thing you use as a library using a simple API, as you're expecting.
There are different approaches which might have different success in different scenarios, but don't expect it to work out of the box.

A good solution might be SIFT algorithm 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform
but it's patented and might be too computationaly intensive. I read about SURF algorithm as being a free and faster alternative. You'll have to put in some work in evaluating those for your scenarios, but I wouldn't expect it to work 100%.

I think SIFT is available as part of OpenCV other guys mentioned, but I am not sure about SURF.